# Accessing scope variable in directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

At the moment I have this directive that checks if the username entered by the user already exists in the database -

```
app.directive('usernameAvailable', function ($timeout, $q, userService, authService) {
    return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attr, model) {
        model.$asyncValidators.Username = function () {


                var User = {
                    Username: model.$viewValue
                }

                var defer = $q.defer();

                var promiseGet = userService.DoesUsernameExist(User);
                promiseGet.then(function (result) {

                    scope.$emit('updateUsername', model.$viewValue);

                    if (result.data == true) {
                        model.$setValidity('Username', false);
                    } else {
                        model.$setValidity('Username', true);
                    }

                },
                function (errorResult) {
                    console.log('Unable to check if the username exists', errorResult);
                });

                return defer.promise;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

This works, but my issue is that when you try to edit a user it will say that the username is already taken since it already exists in the database. I want to pass a variable ($scope.InitialUsername) so that i can put a condition in my directive that the username is allowed to equal this when editing a user.

This will also mean passing in a variable for editmode to allow this condition to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wawhDgPy9DF6id0rqphz?p=preview)
Any directive does have a `scope` variable where you can bind specific informations to

```
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      initialUserName: '=name'
    },
  };
})
```

And in your html you can access this property like this:

`<my-directive name="tom"></my-directive>`

And on the template side you can query the name like

`{{initialUserName.name}}`

Comment: Hi, I'm still a bit confused about how to get this to work exactly. I have an object in my controller called $scope.user which holds username, email etc, but how do I assign this with the syntax you mentioned? initialUsername : '=user.Username' is not right, so what is the right way?

Comment: You have controller and you might have any html where you apply your controller code right? If so, you surely have a directive in that html code. and on this directive you put your stuff `<my-directive name='user.Username'></my-directive>` hope this helpes you out.

Comment: Ah right yeah I have it working now. I have <div ... my-directive attr-username={{initialUsername}} >...</div> then in the directive I can just do  scope: {initialUsername: '=attr-username' }. Thanks! Btw your plnkr link doesn't seem to link to any example. You may want to update if anyone else sees this post :)